# Calculate polygon area in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop

Please please please help me figure out what the deal is with my area units!!When calculate geometry for census tracts in km^2, I am given back some absurd, meaningless number such as 0.000696186

Comment: Sounds like it could be in square Decimal Degrees rather than square Kilometres.  Check your data frame and dataset's properties to see what coordinate system you are using.  If that does not resolve it please post a screenshot of those properties and the Calculate Geometry settings you used.

Comment: This is FAQ: you will find it answered by searching our site using various combinations of keywords like "area", "calculate", and "decimal degrees".  [Here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=area+arcgis+decimal+degrees) are the results of one short effective search.